# Decrypt from cipher text encrypted using RSA

Tags: encryption, cryptography, linux, openssl, rsa

I am sniffing a client side application traffic and I found some encrypted data. I am not able to decrypt it. Information which I have is

Public Key:

```
MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgHfIm5pYrEMUuJUevmED6bUFx8p9G/5vF+ia+Qnrn8OeMpIJ/KS2nqDLxXx/ezNKlFArWK1Wer4diwQJ2cdiCqNorubAgnOXMV+/FsiATQjMT2E2lI9xUWqqNq+PfgyCPILRliNHT/j2qOvAOHmf3a1dP8lcpvw3x3FBBKpqtzqJAgMBAAE=
```

Private Key:

```
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
```

Encrypted string:

```
MpTF1+cqa23PdxQ6EoG9E77jfRJGYjORc4omawTg/g8jtUDZNNEeEr3waadTSLjQAfmJO94fpaA145yanoU9khrzCd/nAGIIAVwMC67UnsX+XY6dOEZMo41Z0dU1n42rUtkdXgldHXR1SQXaeDyjRnMj/mMMreNdykl8b4vNVPk=
```

I am able to retrieve all the keys, But I am not able to  view encrypted content. Help me to decrypt with procedures.

Comment: The strings are all encoded in base64. Now, how does one interpret them it's another business. Can you name the application or not? Can you RE it?

Comment: RSA public key, private key, and data will be in base64 right?(Correct me if am wrong.)

Comment: That's right, those strings are all [most probably] base64. You can tell from the charset and the trailing =s

Comment: How to do it so?

Comment: You would have to understand how the private and public keys are represented. Is the application a windows or linux binary? What does it link to? Can you reverse engineer it?

Comment: The application for MAC. Application store private in a file in local machine. It send public key to server to pass a authentication token. Server will encrypt authentication token with the public send by client machine.

Comment: Is SSL used here or some other protocol?

Comment: NO.. There is no SSL used in app.

Comment: If it doesn't use a standard library your best approach is decompiling it. Consider that this may be illegal, depending on the EULA and where do you live in

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Start with saving the three parts respectively to `pub.b64`, `priv.b64` and `blob.b64`:

```
$ base64 -d < pub.b64 | openssl asn1parse -inform DER -i

    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 158 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 140 prim:  BIT STRING
```

Clearly not an X.509v3 certificate. No matter, we don't need that to decrypt. `openssl dumpasn1` isn't up to the heavy lifting here, try Peter Gutmann's [`dumpasn1`](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/) to peek inside the bit string:

```
$ base64 -d < pub.b64 > pub.der
$ dumpasn1 -al pub.der

   0  158: SEQUENCE {
   3   13:   SEQUENCE {
   5    9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
         :       (PKCS #1)
  16    0:     NULL
         :     }
  18  140:   BIT STRING, encapsulates {
  22  136:     SEQUENCE {
  25  128:       INTEGER
         :         77 C8 9B 9A 58 AC 43 14 B8 95 1E BE 61 03 E9 B5
         :         05 C7 CA 7D 1B FE 6F 17 E8 9A F9 09 EB 9F C3 9E
         :         32 92 09 FC A4 B6 9E A0 CB C5 7C 7F 7B 33 4A 94
         :         50 2B 58 AD 56 7A BE 1D 8B 04 09 D9 C7 62 0A A3
         :         68 AE E6 C0 82 73 97 31 5F BF 16 C8 80 4D 08 CC
         :         4F 61 36 94 8F 71 51 6A AA 36 AF 8F 7E 0C 82 3C
         :         82 D1 96 23 47 4F F8 F6 A8 EB C0 38 79 9F DD AD
         :         5D 3F C9 5C A6 FC 37 C7 71 41 04 AA 6A B7 3A 89
 156    3:       INTEGER 65537
         :       }
         :     }
         :   }
```

That's more like it, we have what appears to be a 1024-bit modulus, and a likely public exponent of 65537.

The key is a base64 encoded normal RSA key in DER (binary) format:

```
$ base64 -d priv.b64 | openssl rsa -inform DER > out.key
writing RSA key
$ cat out.key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you decode that key:

```
$ openssl asn1parse  < out.key
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 600 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=3 l= 128 prim: INTEGER           
                      :77C89B9A58AC4314B8951EBE6103E9B505C7CA7D1BFE6F17E89AF9
                       09EB9FC39E329209FCA4B69EA0CBC57C7F7B334A94502B58AD567A
                       BE1D8B0409D9C7620AA368AEE6C0827397315FBF16C8804D08CC4F
                       6136948F71516AAA36AF8F7E0C823C82D19623474FF8F6A8EBC038
                       799FDDAD5D3FC95CA6FC37C7714104AA6AB73A89
  138:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
  [...snip...]
```

and compare with the `dumpasn1` decoding of the public key, you can see that they share a 1024 bit modulus and exponent, so it looks like the public and private key match. Good.

So, decode your encrypted data:

```
$ base64 -d blob.b64 > blob
```

and decrypt it:

```
$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey out.key < blob > decrypted
$ hexdump decrypted
0000000 0355 1739 575b 5434 ccc5 bec7 e70a 0d44
0000010 a4a9 11d4 166c 3423 4e36 e657 2fea ef53
```

That's 32 bytes (256 bits), quite likely a key used in a symmetric cipher to encrypt more data, since you [can only encrypt relatively small amounts of data with RSA](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security)

Good luck with the next part ;-)

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: Thanks spuratic. As far as i understood that key.b64 contains public key, crt.b64 contains private key and blob.b64 contains ciphertext. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `crt.b64` is the public key, since it turns out it's not an actual cert, I'll rename it to be more obvious. In general the "public key" is wrapped up in a cert, hence the name I used.

Comment: For a key whose algorithm-specific data is ASN.1 (RSA DSA DH but not EC) you can use `openssl asn1parse [-inform d/p] -strparse N` where N is the location of the BITSTRING wrapper, in this example 18. Also now you often don't need a separate base64-d; for `asn1parse` (only) `-inform pem` doesn't check the dash-BEGIN/END lines and accepts any base64, but below 1.1.0 the line length must not exceed 76 (which this example does); 1.1.0 as of 2016 allows about 1000.

Comment: You are a master!

Answer (score 5):

After decoding the strings from base64 to binary, you should try the following, depending on the algorithm used.

This encodes from base64 to binary. You probably would have to do it with the keys, too (or just decode them manually)

```
$ openssl enc -in ciphertext -out binarytext -d -a
```

And to perform the decryption:

```
$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -in binarytext -out plaintext -inkey private.pem
```