# Is it possible to combine RSA and XOR?

Tags: rsa

For my project in uni I need to combine asymmetric and symmetric cryptosystems. I wanted to do thing with AES and RSA but it's a little difficult for me and I want something easier. So I thought that maybe I can go with these steps:

1. the message is encrypted with a symmetric algorithm (XORcipher)
2. the key of the symmetric algorithm is encrypted by the asymmetric algorithm (RSA)

Comment: Welcome to the community. What's your goal? Why do you need to combine them if you understand that yourself?

Comment: Why don't you use just [libsodium Authenticated encryption](https://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption) it is well maintained library and has many ports, too. You will get, confidential, integrity, and authentication>

Answer (score 1):

Using XOR for encryption requires you to have a key which is at least as long as the data you want to encrypt - or you would need to repeat the key which is insecure. This means there is no actual advantage for a hybrid encryption using RSA+XOR, you could directly encrypt the data with RSA and skip key generation and XOR.

But, you can only encrypt a short amount of data with RSA - see [RSA maximum bytes to encrypt, comparison to AES in terms of security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security). This limits the size of the key you can encrypt and thus also the size of the message.

Comment: I think p_1+p_2+...+p_n key length is already enough, if p_1\*p_2\*...\*p_n is larger than the data. :-)